# Finding 'Characters' based on specific 'item' (character has array of items)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am attempting to use a query that will search my DB for characters who currently have a specific item and then console.log the characters.

The items are actually referenced models.

Ex:

Character

```
var characterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    items: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Item"
            }
        ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Character", characterSchema);
```

Item

```
var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    owners: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Character"
            }
        ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);
```

So far I have tried this:

```
Character.find({"items": "Greatsword"}, function(err, characters) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(characters);
    }
});
```

I figured this wouldn't work since "items" within the character is just an array referencing items, but I am not sure where to go from here..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation to join the referenced documents and then search on them.

```
Character.aggregate([
    // deconstruct array field (as you can't join on an array field)
    { 
        $unwind: '$items' 
    },
    // join items collection
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: 'items', // collection to join
            localField: 'items', // field from the input documents
            foreignField: '_id', // field from the documents of the "from" collection
            as: 'item' // output array field 
        }
    },
    // deconstruct array field
    { 
        $unwind: '$item' 
    },
    // filter
    {
        $match: {
            'item.name': 'Greatsword'
        }
    },
    // rebuild
    {
        _id: '_id',
        name: { $first: '$name' }, 
        items: { $push: '$item' }
    }
], function (err, characters) {

});
```

For more information, read

- [$unwind array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-array)
- [$lookup with an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#unwind-example)
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#examples)

Comment: Damn, seems like a lot of work for something so simple. Thank you!